# ¿Cómo poner advertencia en una etiqueta "a" en html?

Tags: html, html5

Actualmente estoy con una duda y es más que todo teórica que práctica, estoy estudiando el curso html de mozilla y me encontre con una pregunta que son lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código viene a ser el siguiente:

```
    <p>We do lots of work with Narwhals. To find out more about this work,<a href="narwhals.html" target="_blank">click here</a>.</p>

    <p>You can email our support team if you have any more questions — <a href="mailto:whales@example.com">click here</a> to do so.</p>

    <p>You can also <a href="factfile.pdf" target="_blank">click here</a> to download our factfile, which contains lots more information, including an FAQ.</p>
```

A lo que quiero llegar es que quiero confirma mi teoría si es correcta o errónea, en la primera pregunta solo es cambiar el "click here" por un nombre apropiado y en el segundo punto agregar un atributo "title" a cada etiqueta "a".

Comment: Has entendido bien. Para resolver el primer punto, te recomiendo leer [este artículo](http://stephanieleary.com/2015/05/why-click-here-is-a-terrible-link-and-what-to-write-instead/) sobre el correcto uso de los enlaces.

Comment: Gracias compañero :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

se refiere a algo de este estilo.

```
  <p>We do lots of work with Narwhals. To find out more about this work, visit <a href="narwhals.html" target="_blank"> Narwhals Web Page</a>.</p>

    <p>You can <a href="mailto:whales@example.com">send an email our support team</a> if you have any more questions.</p>

    <p>You can also <a href="factfile.pdf" target="_blank">download our factfile</a>, which contains lots more information, including an FAQ.</p>
```

Comment: Explica en qué consiste tu solución. Además, no estás usando `title` ¿?

Comment: Gracias compañero, en si como me dice que arroje alertas como en la segunda pregunta, pensé en poner un title y no se si estaría bien ponerle

Comment: @SirAngel el enunciado tiene trampa: *...que necesiten una advertencia*. Si el texto que usas en lugar de `Click here` es suficientemente descriptivo, el `title` estaría de más y podrías omitirlo. Puedes consultar: [How to Use the Link Title Attribute Correctly](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/link-title-attribute/).

Comment: Gracias compañero, un saludo :D